# Mapping nJupiter to a internal LDAP server

Tags: ldap, membership-provider

I am trying to use nJupiter LDAP Membership provider for an internal Tivoli based LDAP server.

I can log on with the userid, which in our case is a combination of country code and serial #, but would like to log in with the e-mail address instead. (or both if possible).

My users config is:

```
<users>
    <filter value="(objectclass=person)"/>
    <base value="ou=intranet,o=company.com" />
    <rdnAttribute value="uid" />
    <attributes>
      <!-- These attributes are loaded together with the LdapMembershipUser -->
      <!-- and also used by the FindUsersByName if excludeFromNameSearch not set to true -->
      <attribute value="givenName" />
      <attribute value="sn" />
      <attribute value="mail"/>
      <attribute value="title" excludeFromNameSearch="true" />
      <attribute value="callupName" excludeFromNameSearch="true" />
    </attributes>
    <descriptionAttribute value="cn" />
    <membershipAttribute value="ibm-allGroups" />
    <creationDateAttribute value="timeStampOnboard" />
    <emailAttribute value="mail" />
  </users>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on what needs to change to use mail as the logon for windows forms?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is change this line:
`<rdnAttribute value="uid"/>`

to something more like:
`<rdnAttribute value="mail"/>`

I.e. Use the presented value (what the user enters as a user name) to match a mail attribute value instead of a uid attribute value.